# How to Convert Just a Sulawesi Map to Leaflet

Tags: qgis, openstreetmap, leaflet, web-gis

I'm still develop a Web GIS that show population distribution in form of heat map. I'm use Quantum GIS with Open Street Map & Q2Leaflet Plugin as a tool to accomplish it.
The problem is, I just want to show the population distribution of Sulawesi, but when I download data via Open Street Map, I ended up download the World Map. I just want to use Sulawesi Map, convert it to leaflet & embed it to my Web GIS.

How should I do to convert ONLY Sulawesi Map into leaflet?

Answer (score 1):

I think you will be best off using a tile server, and then your heat map on top. You don't want to be publishing your own OpenStreetMap.

Follow this guide here: http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/leaflet_maps_with_qgis2leaf.html

Just replace the points dataset with your dataset.